# Possible to pass UTF-8/UTF-16 options to JVM invoked from C++?

Tags: c++, utf-8, jvm

I've got a Windows C++ program where I want to invoke a JVM and be able to pass it an option that might be given from the command line invocation of the C++ program (the command line option might not be plain text, for example "-Dblah=japan日本").  The JavaVMOption struct in jni.h appears to define the option string as chars only, so it looks like I can't just pass it a wide string.

I tried converting it to UTF-8 and storing it as a narrow string on the C++ side and then on the Java side to convert it back, but it seems the "日本" gets replaced with the actual "??" characters, and thus are lost in the conversion-unconversion process.

Am I thinking about this incorrectly?  Would this not be expected to work?

Comment: You may find this mail interesting: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jdk8-dev/2011-July/000058.html

Comment: @kol: yes, very interesting - thanks.  That would be a very welcome improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The invocation [api documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/invocation.html) makes it clear:

```
typedef struct JavaVMOption {
    char *optionString;  /* the option as a string in the default platform encoding */
    void *extraInfo;
} JavaVMOption;
```

The term "default platform encoding" is unambiguous, that does *not* mean utf-8 on Windows.  It means the encoding used by the default system code page.  If your machine is not configured to use a Japanese code page (like 932) then the conversion from the utf-16 string is going to produce question marks for Japanese characters that cannot be converted.  This is not normally a problem since a Japanese user will have the correct code page selected.  No workaround for having the wrong one.

Ensure you've got the correct system code page selected, Control Panel + Region and Language to change.  And use WideCharToMultiByte() with CP_ACP to make the conversion.

Comment: IMHO, CP936 should be the code page for Simplified Chinese(GBK), not Japanese. For Japanese(Shift-JIS), the code page is CP932.

Comment: @Hans: thanks for setting me straight.  I was hoping for too much.